How to implement global search filter on angular primeng datatable with custom formarray component?
So I am trying to implement a global search filter inside a custom component and it doesn't seem to work. I've tried a couple different ways, hence posting here for some assistance. The component works fine without filering but when I add the search filter and try to update the details of a specific row after filtering, the updated values are not going to the backend. Maybe something is wrong in the way I've implemented the filtering.
Posting code snippets below for your reference. I've removed lines for simplicity.
The custom component html:
<ng-container>
  <form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <div [formArrayName]="formarrName">
      <div class="">
        <p-table
          #table
          responsiveLayout="stack"
          [breakpoint]="'960px'"
          [value]="formarr.controls"
          [(selection)]="selectedRecords"
        >
          <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
            <div class="flex">
              <div class="relative ml-auto">
                <input
                  pInputText
                  id="datatable_search_textfield"
                  type="search"
                  class="dt-search-input"
                  (input)="filterTable($any($event.target).value)"
                  placeholder="Search..."
                  required
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </ng-template>

          <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <tr>
              <th style="width: 5%"></th>
              <th *ngFor="let config of configuration">{{ config.header }}</th>
            </tr>
          </ng-template>
          <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-control let-i="rowIndex">
            <tr [formGroupName]="i">
              <td class="flex justify-center sm:justify-start">
                <p-tableCheckbox
                  class="pt-[13px] pb-[28px]"
                  [value]="i + 1"
                ></p-tableCheckbox>
              </td>
              <td *ngFor="let config of configuration">
                <input
                  [type]="'text'"
                  [id]="config.controlId"
                  [name]="config.formcontrolName"
                  [formControlName]="config.formcontrolName"
                />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </ng-template>
        </p-table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  <div>
    <cust-btn (click)="onAdd.emit()" labelText="Add Row"></cust-btn>
    <cust-btn (click)="onSubmit.emit()" labelText="Submit"></cust-btn>
    <cust-btn (click)="onDelete()" labelText="Delete Row"></cust-btn>
  </div>
</ng-container>

Custom component ts:
export class CustomFormArrComponent{
  @Output('onAdd') onAdd: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output('onSubmit') onSubmit: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Input() formarr: FormArray = new FormArray<any>([]);
  @Input() selectedRecords: any[] = [];
  @Input() formArrayValues: any[] = [];
  @Input() configuration: Config[] = [];
  @Input() formGroup: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  @Input() nameOfFormArr: string = '';
  filteredFormArray: FormArray = new FormArray<any>([]);

  constructor() {}

  get props(): FormArray {
    return this.formGroup.get(this.nameOfFormArr) as FormArray;
  }

  public filterTable(value: any) {
    const searchText = value.toLowerCase();
    this.filteredFormArray.clear();
    if (value.length > 0) {
      this.props.controls.filter((group: AbstractControl) => {
        this.configuration.map((val: FormArrayInput) => {
          let controlValue = group.get(val.formcontrolName)?.value;
          if (
            controlValue != null &&
            typeof controlValue != 'boolean' &&
            controlValue.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)
          ) {
            this.filteredFormArray.push(group);
          }
        });
      });
      this.formarr = this.filteredFormArray;
    } else {
      this.formarr = this.props;
    }
  }


  public onDelete() {

    let sortedVal: number[] = [...this.selectedRecords].sort(
      (a, b) => a - b
    );

    sortedVal.reverse().forEach((index) => {
      this.props.removeAt(index - 1);
    });

    this.selectedRecords = [];
  }

Parent component typescript where I am calling this custom component:
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  public selectedRows: any = [];

  public parentConfiguration: Config[] = configurationData;

  public parentForm: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    Something: [],
    SomethingElse: [],
    ArrayProps: new FormArray([]),
  });

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  get arrayProps(): FormArray {
    return this.parentForm.get('ArrayProps') as FormArray;
  }

  public onAdd() {
    this.arrayProps.push(this.addControls());
  }

  private addControls() {
    return new FormGroup({
      Field: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      SecondField: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    });
  }

  private populateFormArray() {
    this.savedDataFromBackend.forEach((data, index) => {
      this.onAdd();
      this.arrayProps.controls[index].setValue(data);
    });
  }

  public onSubmit(): void {
    //This is where all the posting goes
    console.log(this.parentForm.value);
  }

Parent component html:
        <cust-formarr
          [formControlConfig]="parentConfiguration"
          [formarr]="arrayProps"
          [selectedRecords]="selectedRows"
          [formGroup]="parentForm"
          [formArrayControlName]="'ArrayProps'"
          (onSubmit)="onSubmit()"
          (onAdd)="onAdd()"
        ></cust-formarr>

Configuration Data:
export var configuration: Config[] = [
  {
    header: 'Test',
    controlId: 'function',
    formcontrolName: 'function',
  }
];

I tried looking for some sample solutions that I can use for ideas but couldn't find any so I wrote this on my own. Hoping someone here can help me figure out how to get the global search to work. Thanks!
